# Programmatic Spinner spacing issue

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to have Spinner dropdown width similar to the Spinner View.
So that when drop down is expanded, it can completely overlap with Spinner view.

But i got into a problem.
I have created 2 spinners to explain my situation.

## Dimension

form_screen_equipment_combo_box_dropdown_vertical_offset = -50dp

One from XML layout. (Gives me expected result)

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/equipment_selector"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/combo_box_bg"
android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/form_screen_equipment_combo_box_dropdown_vertical_offset"
android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
android:popupBackground="@drawable/combo_box_bg"
android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Another dynamically from java code.  (Problematic Spinner)

```
Spinner view = new Spinner(context, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

**"view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);"  This line solved my problem.**

view.setLayoutParams(new        LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
CustomSpinnerAdapter equipmentAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context, 0,     Arrays.asList(values));
view.setAdapter(equipmentAdapter);
view.setPrompt(title);
view.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.combo_box_bg));
view.setDropDownWidth(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
view.setDropDownVerticalOffset(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.form_screen_equipment_combo_box_dropdown_vertical_offset));
view.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.combo_box_bg));
```

In second spinner i have unexpected space, i checked through UIAutomator and it seems dropdown view's width is lesser than the Spinner view.
Attached screenshot of second spinner for reference. [image: Problematic Spinner]
Can you please suggest required code changes to fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: from where did you got your combo_box_bg drawable?

Comment: It's a nine patch stretchable image.

Comment: what if you try with a native Android resource for each dropdown item? Does it still happen?

Comment: @joao2fast4u i was getting same result with android resource for dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited my answer above. It seems Spinner widget add padding by default when created programmatically. Had to reset that 0.